# MockExcpetionError when trying to test if a method is called

Tags: ruby, mocking, minitest, stubbing

I am trying to test the below block of code to make sure that when I call start_game that it calls the make_rand_num method.

```
  def make_rand_num
    @prng1 = Random.new(@seed)
  end

  def start_game
    make_rand_num
  end
```

Here is the test that I have written to try to make sure that make_rand_num is called when start_game is called.

```
  def test_game_start
    double = Minitest::Mock.new('double')
    double.expect :make_rand_num, Random
    @game.start_game
    assert_mock double
  end
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing a point of mocking/stubbing as I am new to testing and Ruby, but I keep getting this error:

```
MockExpectationError: expected make_rand_num() => Random
```

Shouldn't make_rand_num return an object of type Random, or am I just missing some other point completely?